# Running a command within a launched shell within an apptainer instance

Tags: bash, shell, singularity-container, apptainer

I'm working towards setting up a script for batch submission to an HPC system which uses software in an apptainer image. Here's what I have in mind:

```
apptainer run container.sif runjob.sh


runjob.sh
--------------------
./loadenv.sh
python3 job.py
```

Where loadenv.sh is ~160 line script that sets up paths/etc and launches a new shell with:

```
$NEW_SHELL "$@"
```

With the new shell being launched, bash commands stop being processed until the shell exits. Is there a way to pass the job to the new shell without editing loadenv.sh?

Comment: Very vaguely worded question, but I would comment that normally if you have a script that sets up PATHs, you have to source it like ```. loadenv.sh``` or ```source loadenv.sh``` otherwise it is lost when the subshell exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "$@" accepts command line arguments entered after it as variables.

editing runjob.sh to:

```
./loadenv.sh python3 job.py
```

runs the job in the environment. I found this only works for 1 argument, with the shell exiting on completion. So to run multiple jobs in the same batch submission it needs to be structured as:

```
apptainer run container.sif runjob.sh


runjob.sh
--------------------
./loadenv.sh python3 job1.py
./loadenv.sh python3 job2.py
./loadenv.sh python3 job3.py
...
```